# Discord Js - Bot can't react to message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make a poll command, where the bot send an embed with the poll and afterwards reacts to it with some emojis. I added the reaction Intent to my index.js but still get an error everytime I call the command. This is my code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders')
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("poll")
        .setDescription("Create a quick poll.")
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName("question").setDescription("The question").setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const question = interaction.options.getString("question")
        const message = await interaction.reply({embeds: [
            new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('GREEN')
                .setTitle(`Discord Poll`)
                .setAuthor(`Requested by ${interaction.member.user.tag}`, interaction.member.user.avatarURL())
                .setDescription(question)
                .setThumbnail('https://pngimg.com/uploads/question_mark/question_mark_PNG126.png')
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter('Bot by Iuke#4681', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/912052946592739408.png?size=96')
        ]})
        message.react(':check:')
        .then(() => message.react(':neutral:')
        .then(() => message.react(':xmark:')))
    }
}
```

And get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'react')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to fetch the [reply](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=reply). You can use the [`fetchReply`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/InteractionReplyOptions) option and set it to true.

```js
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('poll')
    .setDescription('Create a quick poll.')
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName('question')
        .setDescription('The question')
        .setRequired(true),
    ),
  async execute(interaction) {
    const question = interaction.options.getString('question');
    const message = await interaction.reply({
      embeds: [
        new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('GREEN')
          .setTitle(`Discord Poll`)
          .setAuthor(
            `Requested by ${interaction.member.user.tag}`,
            interaction.member.user.avatarURL(),
          )
          .setDescription(question)
          .setThumbnail(
            'https://pngimg.com/uploads/question_mark/question_mark_PNG126.png',
          )
          .setTimestamp()
          .setFooter(
            'Bot by Iuke#4681',
            'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/912052946592739408.png?size=96',
          ),
      ],
      fetchReply: true,
    });

    // you could use await to react in sequence instead of then()s
    await message.react(':check:');
    await message.react(':neutral:');
    await message.react(':xmark:');
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/InteractionReplyOptions) you need to add the [`fetchReply`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/InteractionReplyOptions) option on [`interaction.reply`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=reply) like this:

```js
const message = await interaction.reply({ content: 'Pong!', fetchReply: true });
```